# В чем ошибка, почему выполняется только первое условие?

Tags: javascript

```js
let n = prompt("Число ворон?", 15);
console.log("n=",n);
let a;
if (n = 1) {
  a = "а";
  alert(`На ветке сидел${a} ${n} ворон${a}`);
} else if (n >= 2 && n < 5) {
  a = "ы";
  alert(`На ветке сидело ${n} ворон${a}`);
} else if (n = 5 && n <= 20) {
  alert(`На ветке сидело ${n} ворон`);
}
```

Comment: if (n **==** 1), else if (n **>=** 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let n = +prompt("Число ворон?", 15);
let a1 = "", a2 = "";
let n1 = n % 10, n10 = n % 100;
if ((n10 >= 11 && n10 <= 19) || (n1 >= 5 && n1 <= 9) || (n1 == 0)) {
  a1 = "о";
  a2 = "";
} else if (n1 == 1) {
  a1 = "a";
  a2 = "a";
} else if (n1 >= 2 && n1 < 5) {
  a1 = "и";
  a2 = "ы";
}
alert(`На ветке сидел${a1} ${n} ворон${a2}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что в первом условии не сравнивается `==`, а сразу присваивается `n = 1`.